# How to get rid of that ugly acute ("anw tonos") in the greek alphabetical numerals?

Tags: xetex, subcaption, polyglossia, greek

When using subcaptions in a figure, in a greek document (LaTeX or XeTeX), the labels are numbered with (α'), (β'), (γ') and so on, as shown below. Is there a way to remove the 's ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{subcaption}
  \setmainfont{Arial}
  \setmainlanguage{greek}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{0.4cm}{1cm}
    \caption{θάλασσα}\label{fig:a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{0.4cm}{1cm}
    \caption{ήλιος}\label{fig:b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A minimal example would be a good start for trying and find a better than horrible approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make `\anw@true` the same as `\anw@false`; I'll show a second level `enumerate`, with subcaptios it will be the same, as they use the Greek version of `\alph` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}

  \setmainfont{Old Standard}
  \setmainlanguage{greek}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[greek]{babel}
\fi

\makeatletter
\let\anw@true\anw@false
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
  \item 2
  \item 3
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

### Output with `pdflatex` and `babel`:

[image]

### Output with `xelatex` and `polyglossia`:

[image]

## Example with `subcaption`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}

  \setmainfont{Old Standard}
  \setmainlanguage{greek}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[greek]{babel}
\fi

\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\let\anw@true\anw@false
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \rule{0.4cm}{1cm}
  \caption{θάλασσα}\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}% <---------------- don't forget!
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \rule{0.4cm}{1cm}
  \caption{ήλιος}\label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output has been produced with `pdflatex`, it's the same, apart from fonts, with `xelatex`.

[image]